# Strange C function - What is this function doing?

Tags: c, function

I encountred this function without any comment. I wonder what is this function doing? Any help?

```
int flr(int n, char a[])
{
    #define A(i) a[((i) + k) % n]
    int l[n], ls = n, z[n], min = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        l[i] = i;
        z[i] = 1;
    }

    for (int k = 0; ls >= 2; k++)
    {
        min = l[0];
        for (int i=0; i<ls; i++) min = A(l[i])<A(min) ? l[i] : min;
        for (int i=0; i<ls; i++) z[A(l[i])!=A(min) ? l[i] : (l[i]+k+1)%n] = 0;
        for (int ls_=ls, i=ls=0; i<ls_; i++) if (z[l[i]]) l[ls++] = l[i];
    }

    return ls == 1 ? l[0] : min;
}
```

Comment: The awkward moment, when you realize that `flr`, `l`, `z` are sensible names only when you write the code:D

Comment: Just a wild guess - `flr` is maybe `floor` and finding some minimums are involved too. Try to debug the code line by line.

Comment: you need a multiplcation there to have a matrix.

Comment: At least a[] is of length n...

Comment: beeing a lazy person I would first check the code which is calling this.. maybe there's some clue there

Comment: This function is doing something crazy! Analysing random cryptic code is not among the things that SO encourages

Comment: Can you give some more context?

Comment: I encountred that as an independent snippet in my code from past. I saved it for further analysis years ago. :D

Comment: What subject is it? physics, crypto, filesystem, ...

Comment: I think that it is a De-compiled code.

Comment: With a statement like `int l[n];` this code isn't valid and won't compile because there's no VLA's in C.

Comment: Wow, this is a beauty: `z[A(l[i])!=A(min) ? l[i] : (l[i]+k+1)%n] = 0;`. Something is zeroed, but nobody knows where. I would print this out, hang it on the wall, and then start over writing a new function.

Comment: @acraig5075 There is VLA in c99.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What a fun problem!

Other posters are correct that it returns the index of a minimum, but it's actually more interesting than that.

If you treat the array as being circular (i.e. when you get past the end, go back to the beginning), the function returns **the starting index of the minimum lexicographic subsequence**.

If only one element is minimal, that element is returned. If multiple elements are minimal, we compare the next element along from each minimal element.

E.g. with an input of `10` and `{0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}`:

- There are four minimal elements of 0, at indices 0, 6, 7 and 9
- Of these two are followed by a 1 (the 0 and 7 elements), and two are followed by a 0 (the 6 and 9 elements). Remember that the array is circular.
- 0 is smaller than 1, so we only consider the 0s at 6 and 9.
- Of these the sequence of 3 elements starting at 6 is '001' and the sequence from 9 is also '001', so they're still both equally minimal
- Looking at the sequence of 4 elements, we have '0010' from element 6 onwards and '0012' from element 9 onwards. The sequence from 6 onwards is therefore smaller and 6 is returned. (I've checked that this is the case).

Refactored and commented code follows:

```
int findStartOfMinimumSubsequence(int length, char circular_array[])
{
    #define AccessWithOffset(index) circular_array[(index + offset) % length]
    int indicesStillConsidered[length], count_left = length, indicator[length], minIndex = 0;

    for (int index = 0; index < length; index++)
    {
        indicesStillConsidered[index] = index;
        indicator[index] = 1;
    }

    // Keep increasing the offset between pairs of minima, until we have eliminated all of
    // them or only have one left.
    for (int offset = 0; count_left >= 2; offset++)
    {
        // Find the index of the minimal value for the next term in the sequence,
        // starting at each of the starting indicesStillConsidered
        minIndex = indicesStillConsidered[0];
        for (int i=0; i<count_left; i++) 
            minIndex = AccessWithOffset(indicesStillConsidered[i])<AccessWithOffset(minIndex) ? 
                indicesStillConsidered[i] : 
                minIndex;

        // Ensure that indicator is 0 for indices that have a non-minimal next in sequence
        // For minimal indicesStillConsidered[i], we make indicator 0 1+offset away from the index.
        // This prevents a subsequence of the current sequence being considered, which is just an efficiency saving.
        for (int i=0; i<count_left; i++){
            offsetIndexToSet = AccessWithOffset(indicesStillConsidered[i])!=AccessWithOffset(minIndex) ? 
                indicesStillConsidered[i] : 
                (indicesStillConsidered[i]+offset+1)%length;
            indicator[offsetIndexToSet] = 0;
        }

        // Copy the indices where indicator is true down to the start of the l array.
        // Indicator being true means the index is a minimum and hasn't yet been eliminated.
        for (int count_before=count_left, i=count_left=0; i<count_before; i++) 
            if (indicator[indicesStillConsidered[i]]) 
                indicesStillConsidered[count_left++] = indicesStillConsidered[i];
    }

    return count_left == 1 ? indicesStillConsidered[0] : minIndex;
}
```

**Sample uses**

Hard to say, really. Contrived example: from a circular list of letters, this would return the index of the shortest subsequence that appears earlier in a dictionary than any other subsequence of the same length (assuming all the letters are lower case).

Comment: Good question! Let's say your array was temperature readings for the last 365 days, and you can remember there was one weird day in the middle of summer when it was as cold as winter. This function would give you the date.

Comment: That's a pretty contrived example, I admit.

You could also use it if you had a faulty server which, as well as having planned downtime, kept dropping out. If you passed an array of, say, response times to the server, this function would tell you a time when it had randomly dropped out (but not for an extended period of planned downtime).

Comment: @Hbcdev: To clarify, by "next minimum index", are you referring to the index of the smallest value greater than the minimum value and located after the minimum value in circular order?

Comment: No. I mean the index of the next element that's also a minimum. And it will actually be as far away in both directions -- I'll update my answer to make that clearer.

Comment: care to come up with some illustrative test data? :) i'm saving this snippet for sure...

Comment: Sure. If you pass in 10 and [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0], I think you should get 6 as the result (the index of the 0 furthest from any other 0 in the circular array). I haven't checked that though, so let me know whether I'm right!

Comment: Sorry for getting this wrong, I've worked it out and am just about to post a better answer. Actually, I'll just edit my existing answer.

Comment: if there are two minima in the array, which one does it pick ? They're equally far from each other after all. It doesn't consistently pick the first or second. What about 3 minima that are equi-distant ?

Comment: @Sander: that's why it's still a mystery function, isn't it? :)

Comment: @SanderDeDycker See updated answer. This explains which minimum will be chosen.

Comment: You nailed it. I just figured this out independently, and extensive tests haven't found a counter example. A simpler way to write this code would be `int min = 0; for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) if (cstrncmp(&(a[i]), &(a[min]), n) < 0) min = i;` where `cstrncmp` is a circular version of `strncmp` (obviously requiring null termination of the original string). +1

Answer (score 1):

It returns the position of the smallest element within the substring of `a` ranging from element `0..n-1`.

Comment: Since n can be greater than size of a, i suspect that it is not true.

Comment: @ushik: That depends on what is stored in the memory outside the buffer.

Comment: There's more to it than that : when the smallest element is in the array more than once, the behavior deviates from what you'd expect from a normal `min` function. It doesn't always pick the first, nor the last.

Answer (score 0):

Test code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int flr(int n, char a[])
{
    #define A(i) a[((i) + k) % n]
    int l[n], ls = n, z[n], min = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        l[i] = i;
        z[i] = 1;
    }

    for (int k = 0; ls >= 2; k++)
    {
        min = l[0];
        for (int i=0; i<ls; i++) min = A(l[i])<A(min) ? l[i] : min;
        for (int i=0; i<ls; i++) z[A(l[i])!=A(min) ? l[i] : (l[i]+k+1)%n] = 0;
        for (int ls_=ls, i=ls=0; i<ls_; i++) if (z[l[i]]) l[ls++] = l[i];
    }

    return ls == 1 ? l[0] : min;
}


int main() {
    printf("   test 1: %d\n", flr(4, "abcd"));
    printf("   test 3: %d\n", flr(6, "10e-10"));
    printf("   test 3: %d\n", flr(3, "zxyghab");
    printf("   test 4: %d\n", flr(5, "bcaaa"));
    printf("   test 5: %d\n", flr(7, "abcd"));
    return 0;
}
```

This code gives following output:

```
[root@s1 sf]# ./a.out 
   test 1: 0
   test 2: 3
   test 3: 1
   test 4: 2
   test 5: 4




1. 0 is the position of `a` in the first case
2. 3 is the position of `-` in second case.
3. 1 is the position of `x` in third case. 
4. 2 is the position of the second `a`.
5. 4 is the position of the `\0`
```

So the function returns the position of smallest element of a character pointer pointed by `a` and it will consider `n` elements. (Thats why it returned the position of `x` in the third case).

But when multiple smallest element available, it does not seems to be work in a predictable way, as it does not return the first occurrence, nor the last.

It should do a error checking for out of bound cases. Which may lead to problem in future.

Comment: I don't understand wh x is returned in the third case. Are you saying you're making sense of this output? :) or are you saying that in third case it returned the lexicographically smallest element in the first n elements?

Comment: It returns lexicographically smallest element in the first n elements.

Comment: Hey @Aftnix, my answer above explains why your fourth test returns 2 rather than 3 or 4. It's not because it's the first minimal element, it's because the subsequence 'aaa' < 'aab' and 'aaa' < 'abc'.

If you try again with `flr(5, "aabca")` I think you'll get a result of 4 (the start of the smallest minimal subsequence) rather than 0 (the earliest minimum element).

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, i will edit my answer with correct info.

Answer (score -1):

so i'm running tests on this.

```
int flr(int n, char a[])
{
#define A(i) a[((i) + k) % n]
int l[n], ls = n, z[n], min = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    l[i] = i;
    z[i] = 1;
}

for (int k = 0; ls >= 2; k++)
{
    min = l[0];
    for (int i=0; i<ls; i++) min = A(l[i])<A(min) ? l[i] : min;
    for (int i=0; i<ls; i++) z[A(l[i])!=A(min) ? l[i] : (l[i]+k+1)%n] = 0;
    for (int ls_=ls, i=ls=0; i<ls_; i++) if (z[l[i]]) l[ls++] = l[i];
}

return ls == 1 ? l[0] : min;
}

int main()
{
int in = 10;
char array[] = {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0}; 

int res = flr(in, array);
printf("expecting res to be 6;\tres = %d\n", res);

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

output was res=9;

Comment: Why would you expect 6? Firstly, it's not the same array as in Hbcdev's example, and secondly, since it's assuming the array is *circular*, starting from position 9 you would have [0, 0, 1], which indeed is the minimum subsequence.